# Spring batch job with multi level chunk

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I need to write a batch jobs, which reads from DB a list of users and then for each user get data from external system which will return data in batch of 50 to 500  and then insert this data to DB.

I have wrote a steps as below

- Tasklet load all users and pass to Reader (step 1) .
- Reader takes all users and then pass one by one to processor (step-2) .
- Processor calls external system and get full data for one user.
- Writer gets this data for each user and insert to DB.

Using SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor , I am running this in paraller but , I want to have a steps as below

- Tasklet load all users and pass to Reader (step-1 ,stepTasklet).
- Reader reads list of all user (step-2,parallelstep).
- Another reader/processor get once chunk of data(50 records) for that user.
- Writer gets  50 records data for each user and insert to DB.

This step need to be in parallel for multiple users and also chunk should be at data level not like currently as user level

Can someone help.

```
    @Bean
    public Job getParallelJob() {
        JobParametersIncrementer jobParametersIncrementers = new JobParametersIncrementer() {

            long count = new Date().getTime();

            @Override
            public JobParameters getNext( JobParameters parameters) {
                return new JobParameters(Collections.singletonMap("count", new JobParameter(count)));
            }
        };
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("paralleljob").incrementer(jobParametersIncrementers)
.start(stepTasklet())
                .next(parallelStep(taskExecutor())).build();
                
    }
```

Comment: The first tasklet that reads users in a list and pass them to step2 is redundant and makes the job inefficient. Why don't you use a single chunk-oriented step where the reader reads users from the database and then the processor enriches items from the external system? This would be more efficient and easier to scale (using a multi-threaded step or a partitioned step).

Comment: that can be done but the real issue is with the external system which returns the data in 50 batches , I need to make it chunk like with spring batch , any idea on that

Comment: Does this mean the system expects a request with a single item and returns 50 items, or does it accept requests with 50 items and returns 50 corresponding results? If it accepts a batch of 50 items, you can do that call in `ItemWriteListener#beforeWrite(List items)` which gives you access to the list of items to be written. With a chunk size of 50, you could do the call in that listener method to conform to what the external system expects.

Comment: system expect request with single item and return 50 items , we have to call it again for same item and see if more data is present ,
I want this step to be as a reader or something